# rss doesn't show unicode instead arabic text in title tag

Tags: xml, rss

here is ma rss code,
this display description in Arabic but in title it doesn't change text

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="utf-8" ?>
<rss version="2.0">
  <channel>
<title>NewsLineME.com - All News</title>
<description>Visit NewsLine for latest news.</description>
<language>ar</language>
<link>http://50.23.16.193/newsline/</link>
<lastBuildDate>Thu, 22 Mar 2012 00:48:13 -0500</lastBuildDate>
<pubDate>Mon, 06 Dec 2011 16:45:00 +0000</pubDate>
<ttl>1800</ttl>
<item>
  <title>&amp;#1607;&amp;#1604; &amp;#1610;&amp;#1578;&amp;#1605;&amp;#1603;&amp;#1606; &amp;#1575;&amp;#1604;&amp;#1593;&amp;#1585;&amp;#1575;&amp;#1602; &amp;#1605;&amp;#1606; &amp;#1578;&amp;#1580;&amp;#1575;&amp;#1608;&amp;#1586; &amp;#1571;&amp;#1586;&amp;#1605;&amp;#1575;&amp;#1578;&amp;#1607; &amp;#1575;&amp;#1604;&amp;#1587;&amp;#1610;&amp;#1575;&amp;#1587;&amp;#1610;&amp;#1577; &amp;#1608;</title>
  <description>
    <![CDATA[&#1575;&#1606;&#1578;&#1602;&#1583; &#1585;&#1574;&#1610;&#1587; &#1573;&#1602;&#1604;&#1610;&#1605; &#1575;&#1604;&#1593;&#1585;&#1575;&#1602; &#1605;&#1587;&#1593;&#1608;&#1583; &#1576;&#1575;&#1585;&#1586;&#1575;&#1606;&#1610; &#1576;&#1588;&#1583;&#1577; &#1585;&#1574;&#1610;&#1587; &#1575;&#1604;&#1608;&#1586;&#1585;&#1575;&#1569; &#1575;&#1604;&#1593;&#1585;&#1575;&#1602;&#1610; &#1606;&#1608;&#1585;&#1610; &#1575;&#1604;&#1605;&#1575;&#1604;&#1603;&#1610; &#1605;&#1578;&#1607;&#1605;&#1575; &#1573;&#1610;&#1575;&#1607; &#1576;&#1575;&#1581;&#1578;&#1603;&#1575;&#1585; &#1575;&#1604;&#1587;&#1604;&#1591;&#1577; &#1608;&#1576;&#1606;&#1575;&#1569; &#1580;&#1610;&#1588; &#1610;&#1571;&#1578;&#1605;&#1585; &#1576;&#1571;&#1608;&#1575;&#1605;&#1585;&#1607;.]]>
  </description>
  <link>http://50.23.16.193/newsline/index.php?file=news_detail/news_detail&amp;translation=ara&amp;id=72&amp;cid=3</link>
  <pubDate>Tue, 20 Mar 2012 11:17:00 -0500</pubDate>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

when you run this file in Firefox it will display description in Arabic but title goes same. Can anybody help me with this problem how to convert those character in Arabic.

Comment: This is done. I noticed that there is &amp; in title is preventing text   to convert into arabic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm surprised that either the title or the description is coming out as you expect, since in both cases you have double-escaped the characters. Specifically, while `&#1606;` might represent an arabic character, `&amp;#1606;` and `<![CDATA[&#1606;]]>` both simply represent the sequence of 7 ascii characters (&, #, 1, 6, 0, 6, ;). If you want your markup treated as markup, don't escape it.